# Custom cursor only shows up on desktop, but when in apps cursor changes to Debian default cursor (16.04)

Tags: 16.04, cursor, cursor-theme

So, I've been having this problem, as I was bored of the classic Ubuntu cursor and went ahead and installed the Oxygen cursor, cursor installed successfully! Meh, sorta. When I'm on desktop custom cursor shows up, but when in some apps (like Firefox or Steam for example), the cursor changes to the default Debian cursor. How can I fix this?

Comment: You will probably be easiest of just using a VPN.

Comment: You mean use a VPN?

Comment: Yes a VPN is probably the easiest method to avoid these restrictions, I think that if you want to do anything with this kind of tech from a nation on embargo a VPN is probably going to be your best bet.

Comment: So you mean a VPN, which just encrypts your network connectin is gonna change my cursor?

Comment: I thought I answered this to a question concerning problems with running CUDA in Cuba, somewhere my comment got switched around.